# It is possible get the media of another user? Instgram API

Tags: php, instagram-api

This code that I took form another web, works! but only when I put my Instagram ID. Otherwise when I want to get  a media from another user (changing the variable `userid`) it stops working.

To be sure I use https://www.otzberg.net/iguserid/index.php to get the user ID.
And to get the Access Token (only with my account): http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

```
<?php
    // Supply a user id and an access token
    $userid = "-----";
    $accessToken = "---";

    // Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }
    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}");
    $result = json_decode($result);
    ?>
<?php if(!empty($result->data)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you posted clearly indicates that the token only works with your own images.

> In order to display **your** Instagram photos on **your** own website,
>   you are required to provide an Instagram Access Token.

You should try a different API or method to show images from another user.

Comment: And can u tell the best way to show the last instagram media form another user? Thanks

Comment: Well you would just use the other user's access token. If you don't know it then you cannot use the API for that user.